# Python nested forloop list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert this working nested forloop into a single line list comprehension & i cannot seem to get it to work. The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
result = []
for x in something:
    for y in x.address:
       m = re.search("some pattern to match",y)
       if m:
         result += [m.group(1)]
```

Any pointers on how do i go about this ?

Comment: So where is the list comprehension?And how it doesn't work? what's the problem exactly?

Comment: is `if` supposed to be inside the `for` block or not?

Comment: It is supposed to be inside the for block.Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a generator expression..

```
matches = ( re.search(r'some pattern to match', y) for x in something
                                                     for y in x.address  )
result = [ m.group(1) for m in matches if m ]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Just curious - why is a generator expression required here ? Assuming i do not have a pattern matching statement,i could all get it working in one line.

Comment: Because you can't store the result of re.search into a variable as part of the list comprehension syntax.

Comment: Thanks,this seems to work. I haven't had a use case in the past to use generators anywhere. i shall read more about it then. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are not really a problem for list comprehensions, as you can nest those there too:

```
lst = []
for y in z:
    for x in y:
        lst.append(f(x))
```

This translates into the following list comprehension:

```
[f(x) for y in z for x in y]
```

And you can easily continue that for multiple levels.

Conditions that decide on whether you want to add something to the list or not also work just fine:

```
lst = []
for x in y:
    if t(x):
        lst.append(f(x))
```

This translated into the following list comprehension with a filter:

```
[f(x) for x in y if t(x)]
```

Of course you can also combine that with multiple levels.

---

Now what *is* some kind of a problem though is when you want to execute something first, then filter on the result of that and append also something that depends on the result. The naive solution would be to move the function call inside and do it twice:

```
rexpr = re.compile('some pattern to match')
[rexpr.search(y).group(1) for x in something for y in x.address if rexpr.search(y)]
```

But this obviously runs the search twice which you generally want to avoid. At this point, you could use some hackish solutions which I generally wouldn’t recommend (as they harm readability). Since your result only depends on the result of the regular expression search, you could also solve this in two steps: First, you search on every element and map them to a match object, and then you filter on those matches and just return the valid ones:

```
[m.group(1) for m in (rexpr.search(y) for x in something for y in x.address) if m]
```

Note that I’m using generator expressions here: Those are essentially the same as list comprehensions, but don’t create the full result as a list but only yield on element at a time. So it’s more efficient if you only want to consume this one by one (which is the case here). After all, you’re only interested in the result from the list comprehension, so the comprehension will consume the generator expression.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. It seems what i really needed here was Generators & thanks for the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
# match function
def match(x):
    m  = re.search("some pattern to match",x)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return None

#list comprehension     
results = [match(y) for x in something for y in x.address if match(y)]
```

Comment: This runs `match()` for each element *twice*.